# Unit Test for Generic function in C#

Tags: c#, unit-testing, generics

Seems to be a popular question but I haven't found the answer yet, so

To be short, I have a generic function that I need to perform `unit test` on it, say

> `public void T[] DoSomething<T>(T input1, T input2)`

Now I need to test if this function works correctly for int, ArrayList, how can I write unit tests in this case, listing all the cases for T is not an option, I'm thinking of just test int and some class instance ?

I also try to use the auto generated unit test from VS2012, something looks like :

```
public void DoSomethingHelper<T>() {
    T item1 = default(T);; // TODO: Initialize to an appropriate value
    T item2 = default(T); // TODO: Initialize to an appropriate value
    T[] expected = null; // TODO: Initialize to an appropriate value
    T[] actual = SomeClass.DoSomething<T>(item1, item2);
    Assert.AreEqual(expected, actual);
    Assert.Inconclusive("Verify the correctness of this test method.");
}
[TestMethod()]
public void AddTest() {
    AddTestHelper<GenericParameterHelper>();
}
```

which is even more confusing to me, what should i put in DoSomethingHelper to initialize variables ? an int, a string or something ?

Can anyone help ? I've heard of Pex and others, but still no one provided me a sample unit test code for this simple function.

Comment: What should `DoSomething` do? Please, use a valid example. If you don't know what the function is supposed to do, you won't be able to unit test it.

Comment: This is a simplified version of my code, I don't think it will matter what that functions does, I just need a valid test so it will execute with whatever we got for the input. Anyway, you can think that's it's just as simple as return these two input1, input2 into an array.

Comment: you are saying your dependency is an int so you need to set item 1 and item 2 as int and call the method and assert if you get it right. What is so complex about this?

Comment: sorry if it's make you confuse, I don't ever tell that "dependency is an int" ? I need to test a generic function<T> for all possible case of input so it will always work regardless of what you input, just as simple as that.

Answer (score 4):

*You might want to check [NUnit’s Generic Test Fixtures](http://nunit.com/blogs/?p=62), for testing with multiple implementations of `T`*

First of all, think about the following: **Why are you creating that function generic?**

If you are writing a generic function/method, it **shouldn't** care about the implementation of the type it is working with. I mean, no more than what you specify in the generic class (eg. `where T : IComparable<T>, new()`, etc.)

So, my suggestion is that you create a dummy class that will fit the requirements of the generic type, and test with it. An example using `NUnit`:

```
class Sample {
    //code here that will meet the requirements of T
    //(eg. implement IComparable<T>, etc.)
}

[TestFixture]
class Tests {

    [Test]
    public void DoSomething() {
        var sample1 = new Sample();
        var sample2 = new Sample();
        Sample[] result = DoSomething<Sample>(sample1, sample2);

        Assert.AreEqual(2, result.Length);
        Assert.AreEqual(result[0], sample1);
        Assert.AreEqual(result[1], sample2);
    }
}
```

**Edit:**
Think about it, and you'll see it works. You might think: "*Well, but what if the body of `DoSomething` has something like...*":

```
if (item1 is int) {
    //do something silly here...
}
```

of course it will fail when testing it with `int`, and you won't notice it since you're testing with the `Sample` class, but think of it as if you were testing a function that sums two numbers, and you had something like:

```
if (x == 18374) {
    //do something silly here...
}
```

You wouldn't identify it either.

Comment: I need that generic function to be tested, of course if I can just test all the cases like you said, I don't need to make up a question here. The question is how can I test a generic function <T>, not what is a good way to code, to prevent using of T or something and if I don't put where : that means I don't want it to be limited of any kind, items can be int, float, struct, enum, class, object, ... all. Sorry about that, but this is not the answer I expected.

Comment: @thienhaflash I still don't understand you. Try to explain yourself better. What you need to understand is that if you are writing a **generic** function, it is because you **don't care** about what type it is, so some specific type shouldn't break the function. In your example (a function that adds the two parameters in an array): How does an `integer` can make it fail, while a `string` can't?

Comment: Hello there, sorry for confusing you. As I told above, what's inside the function<T> should not be important at all, so I put an example like that. Sure, I really don't care what T is, but in this case I will need to know what is the minimum unit test I need to implement to ensure that it's won't be a problem passing all kinds of different degenerated values / variables types in, maybe tests with a null variable, an int, a string, a class or anything, but that means a lot. So I want to know, how people actually test a function<T> to ensure that it will never breaks (and run correctly)

Comment: If a string does not break the function, I still need to worry if a NaN or a null variable or a class instance might break it, right ? So that's why I need to put a test on.

Comment: You should know enough about your method you are testing to know what the expected cases and results are, as well as edge cases.  Test those.  You can't reasonably test every possible input, but rather "classes of inputs", and as the author of the method (or at least someone who knows enough about it to know how to write tests for it), you have to define what those classes of inputs are based on what the method actually does.